# Displaying the text in the multiple lines when retrieving from database

Tags: php, html, css

Hi
   I have a table in which my row contains the text which i retrieve from the database.But i have a small width of row and the data i retrieve is large.And the text exceeds the width of my row so i want to break the data i retrieve into multi lines inside the table row.How can i do it.
   My code is here:

```
$list = $mfidao1->fetchMfi($_GET['id']); 
//print_r($list);
//die;
if(!empty($list))
{
foreach($list as $menu)
{
?>

<tr style="border:none; background-color:#FBFBFB;" >
<td class="topv">Social Mission</td>
<td class="topm" ><div class="txt"><?php echo $menu->mfi_1_a;?></div></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#E8E8E8">
<td class="topv">Address</td>
<td class="topm"><?php echo $menu->mfi_ii_c;?></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#FBFBFB">
<td class="topv">Phone</td>
<td class="topm"><?php echo $menu->mfi_ii_e;?></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#E8E8E8">
<td class="topv">Email</td>
<td class="topm"><?php echo $menu->mfi_ii_d;?></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#FBFBFB">
<td class="topv">Year Established</td>
<td class="topm"><?php echo $menu->mfi_i_c;?></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#E8E8E8">
<td class="topv">Current Legal Status</td>
<td class="topm"><?php echo $menu->mfi_i_d;?></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#FBFBFB">
<td class="topv">Respondent</td>
<td class="topm"><?php echo $menu->mfi_ii_a;?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: HTML ignores carriage returns until you do something to prevent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set width of `<td>`. I think this is the best way to do this rather than word_wrap().

Answer (score 1):

In your css for the table, use "**table-layout:fixed**" - This fixes the td elements width according to the way you want.
" **word-wrap: break-word;** " - this breaks the text in it so that it doesnt go beyond the boundary of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but sound like you could use [chunk_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php)()

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function [wordwrap()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php).

It wraps a string to a given number of characters using a string break character.

Answer (score 0):

you can either use the php function

[php wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/de/function.wordwrap.php)

or styling the td with css so that it uses the word-wrap attribute

[css wordwrap](http://www.css3.info/preview/word-wrap/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the text in your td tags. [Here is a link to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057574/html-td-wrap-text)