# How to force table cell <td> content to wrap?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Heres the entire page
* wrappable is defined in a main.css file

```
/* Wrappable cell
* Add this class to make sure the text in a cell will wrap.
* By default, data_table tds do not wrap.
*/
td.wrappable,
table.data_table td.wrappable {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Heres the entire page:

```
<%@ include file="../../include/pre-header.html" %>
<form id="commentForm" name="commentForm" action="" method="post">



    <ctl:vertScroll height="300" headerStyleClass="data_table_scroll" bodyStyleClass="data_table_scroll" enabled="${user.scrollTables}">
        <ctl:sortableTblHdrSetup topTotal="false" href="show.whatif_edit_entry?   entryId=${entry.entryId}" />
        <table class="data_table vert_scroll_table">



            </tr>
            <tr>
                <ctl:sortableTblHdr styleClass="center" title="Comments" property="comment" type="top">Comments</ctl:sortableTblHdr>
            </tr>


            <c:forEach var="comments" items="${entry.comments}">


                <tr id="id${comments.id}">
                    <td id="comments-${comments.id}" class="wrappable" style="width:400px;">${comments.comment}</td>
                </tr>



            </c:forEach>
            <c:if test="${lock.locked || form.entryId < 0 }">
                <%-- This is the row for adding a new comment. --%>
                    <tr id="commentRow">
                        <td><input type="text" id="comment" name="comment" size="50" maxlength="250" onkeypress="javascript:return noenter();" />
                            <a href="javascript:addComment();"><img src="../images/icon_add.gif" border="0" alt="Add"/></a>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
            </c:if>

        </table>

    </ctl:vertScroll>
</form>
```

It just stretches every time I submit.
This page is within a div also. Do I need to set the width of the div and the table also?

Comment: Where are you defining `wrappable`?

Comment: Where is `.wrappable` class defined? what browser are you using?

Comment: The browser being used is especially important---old versions of IE don't support `max-width`. There are plenty of other things that could be the problem and it's impossible to say without more information, but that's one that can be broke.

Comment: Im basically just trying to keep submitted text to stay within a width and not stretch the table after I sybmit it

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/26560829/1924979

Answer (score 323, accepted):

Use `table-layout:fixed` in the table and `word-wrap:break-word` in the td.

See this example:

```
<html>
<head>
   <style>
   table {border-collapse:collapse; table-layout:fixed; width:310px;}
   table td {border:solid 1px #fab; width:100px; word-wrap:break-word;}
   </style>
</head>

<body>
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
         <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry'sstandarddummytexteversincethe1500s,whenanunknown</td>
         <td>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>3</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna...</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

### DEMO:

```css
table {border-collapse:collapse; table-layout:fixed; width:310px;}
       table td {border:solid 1px #fab; width:100px; word-wrap:break-word;}
```

```html
       <table>
          <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
             <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry'sstandarddummytexteversincethe1500s,whenanunknown</td>
             <td>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>3</td>
             <td></td>
             <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna...</td>
          </tr>
       </table>
```

Comment: You should add the border-collapse:collapse bit to the top part of your answer so people who are visually scanning your answer can get the full answer quickly.

Comment: for little more modifications table {border-collapse:collapse; table-layout:fixed;word-wrap:break-word;}
table td { width:100px; word-wrap:break-word;}

Answer (score 53):

Its works for me.

```
<style type="text/css">

 td {

    /* css-3 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap; 
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: pre-wrap; 
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; 
    white-space: -pre-wrap; 

}
```

And table attribute is:

```
table { 
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 22):

```
td {
overflow: hidden;
max-width: 400px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: maybe you can explain the code so it will be clear for anyone

Comment: it shows neat table, but content is cut; ie. can't see some words if its big content.  `overflow:hidden`

Comment: Hardcoding the max width isn't good though. It won't scale as well to large resolutions, etc. YOu want to allow the table to respond to size correctly.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me when I needed to display "pretty" JSON in a cell:

```
td { white-space:pre }
```

---

### More about the [`white-space` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-prop):

> - `normal` : This value directs user agents to collapse sequences of white space, and break lines as necessary to fill line boxes.
> - `pre` : This value prevents user agents from collapsing sequences of white space.
>       Lines are only broken at preserved newline characters.
> - `nowrap` : This value collapses white space as for `normal`, but suppresses line breaks within text.
> - `pre-wrap` : This value prevents user agents from collapsing sequences of white space.
>       Lines are broken at preserved newline characters, and as necessary to fill line boxes.
> - `pre-line` : This value directs user agents to collapse sequences of white space.
>       Lines are broken at preserved newline characters, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

(Also, see more at the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10937254/8112776).)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Bootstrap responsive table, just want to set the maximum width for one particular column and make text wrapping, making the the style of this column as following also works

```
max-width:someValue;
word-wrap:break-word
```

Comment: Note that `max-width` must be a `px` value, not `%`

Answer (score 4):

Just add:   `word-break: break-word;`     to you table class.

Answer (score 3):

I solve it putting a "p" tag inside of my "td" tag like this:

```
<td><p class="">This is my loooooooong paragraph</p></td>
```

Then add this properties to the class, using max-width to define how wide you want your field to be

```
.p-wrap {
  max-width: 400px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to wrap the data in td then you can use the below code

```
td{
    width:60%;
    word-break: break-word;
    }
```

Comment: This worked great for my purposes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want fix the column you should set width. For example:

`<td style="width:100px;">some data</td>`

Comment: I tried that...it keeps expanding the table for some reason                    <td id="comments-${comments.id}" class="wrappable" style="width:100px">${comments.comment}</td>

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrappable { 
      overflow: hidden; 
      max-width: 400px; 
      word-wrap: break-word; 
}
```

I have tested with the binary data and its working perfectly here.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of tackling the problem if you have long strings (like file path names) and you only want to break the strings on certain characters (like slashes). You can insert [Unicode Zero Width Space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) characters just before (or after) the slashes in the HTML.