# Spread text out inside td

Tags: css, input, html-table

I have an input field inside a td that looks like:

[image]

the text in the field is:

> "this is my text for now but I can't see it all"

As you can see I can only see the start of the text how can I get the rest of the text to display inside the text box without changing the size of the td.
So, to maybe space out over 3 or 4 lines?

CSS is as follows at the moment:

```
height:100px;
width:100% !important;
padding:0px;
overflow:hidden;
```

Comment: Post the full code of table and CSS

Comment: If changing from input to textarea is not an acceptable answer can you provide more information to better ascertain your requirements?

Answer (score -1):

You will probably want to use a textarea rather than input, similar to this question? [Multiple lines of input in <input type="text" />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262472/multiple-lines-of-input-in-input-type-text)

Answer (score -1):

For input inside TD you will have to use textarea unfortunately. See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262472/multiple-lines-of-input-in-input-type-text) also.

`white-space:pre` is what you want when multi-lining a td without an input though:

```
td { white-space:pre }
```

Of course this might not work if your td's width is so big that all the text fits inside without the need to break.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937218/how-to-show-multiline-text-in-a-table-cell) question also.

Comment: The question relates to text in the input field not text in the TD directly?

Comment: made and edit to the answer, thanks. No need to downvote though :)

Comment: Ill remove it now you answered the question ;)