# Multiline text in a table cell using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, text, html-table, word-wrap

I want to show a long paragraph of string into a table cell using bootstrap. It contains some newline characters `\r\n`. I tried to use `style="white-space:pre"` as [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937218/how-to-show-multiline-text-in-a-table-cell) suggests but that breaks bootstrap text wrap. I also tried to change `\r\n`to `<br>` but it does not work. `<br>` shows up as a text.

This is how my table looks like..

```
<table id="table1" class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-2" scope="row">Description</th>
            <td id="description">Very long test with \r\n so I want to show this in multiline and also want to wrap the text using bootstrap.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the pagebreaks to HTML breaks (br tag) works fine in jsfiddle. See my link below. Make sure that when you are generating the HTML you are generating actual < and > symbols, and not the HTML codes.

https://jsfiddle.net/joedonahue/zpj94p0b/

```
<table id="table1" class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-2" scope="row">Description</th>
            <td id="description">Very long test with <br/> so I want to show this in multiline and also want to wrap the text using bootstrap.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: hmmmm yes you are right. Based on your feedback found out that my problem was this jquery code `$('#description').text('this\n has\n newlines);` My solution here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535888/jquery-text-and-newlines Thank you!