# Force line break between specific words in HTML table

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying to set up a table for a survey using `HTML-code`. In some of the cells I have some text that I would like to seperate into three lines at a specific place in the text.

```
Name of education
Salary
Unemployment rate
```

All three lines should be in the same cell.

However, using a `<pre></pre>` tag, as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937218/how-to-show-multiline-text-in-a-table-cell) thread does not work for me.

Does anyone have a tip on how to do this?

Comment: please show what you have tried? adding a <br> tag inside can also solve your problem...you must specify what you tried but didnt worked out..

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned, that I am very new to HTML. The <br> tag worked well! Thank you!

Comment: thats fine...just a friendly suggestion always include what you have tried...google a bit and you will find plenty of sites/resources to go start with...:D

Comment: Accept the answer then if that worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `<br />` or `<br>` tag (both works the same) to get multiple lines inside a cell.

below is an example:

```css
td, tr, table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Cell one
    </td>
    <td>
      Hello, <br /> you can use <br />
      the br tag to get <br />
      multiple lines inside a cell.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```