# How to print 3 server side echo's inside a single td in html table?

Tags: php, html, html-table

I am working on a project to display the results from the database on the UI.So my project is based on file info extraction. So I am calculating MD5,SHA1,SHA256 and I want to display them in the common cell in html table. I have used this link [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937218/how-to-show-multiline-text-in-a-table-cell) and i have modified the table. So after this my table is not aligned properly.

Code here:

```
<tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Help</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l" style="white-space:pre-wrap ; word-wrap:break-word;">

    <? echo "$file_Hash" ?>
    <? echo "$file_SHA1" ?> 
    <? echo "$file_SHA256" ?>   

    </td>
    ........ Remaining code not included.
```

[image]

Is there any proper way to align these 3 lines in like a **pyramid** formation. So that md5 has less length that sha1 and sha256.

Comment: have you tried setting the style of the td to `text-align: center;`?

Comment: style="text-align:justify"

Comment: @Cashbee Its all I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

adding the style `text-align: center;` to the td should do it.