# HTML break tag is visible in the text instead of breaking the line

Tags: java, html, css, struts-1

I have trouble using the break tag to break the text in new line.
Here is what I get in my Web-Browser:
[image]

The text is read from a database table.
Heree the entry:
[image]

And the database entry is created with java.
Here the java code:

```
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append("in Folgender Stückelung : <br />");
                while (itKassette.hasNext()) {
                    KassetteBefuellungZuweisung kassetteBef = (KassetteBefuellungZuweisung) itKassette.next();
                    int Anzahl = kassetteBef.getAnzahl();
                    double inhaltNennwert = kassetteBef.getWert() / Anzahl;
                    if (Anzahl != 0) {
                        sb.append("<br />Inhalt (Nennwert): " + inhaltNennwert + " Anzahl: " + Anzahl);
                    }
                }
```

I also tried to figure out what is wrong by looking in the chrome console.
Here:
[image]

But I didnt found anything wrong there so I searches the HTML-Sourcecode form that site and got something suspicious.
Here the HTML:
[image]
For any reason the browser convertet the encoding!
This is a Struts project and Im pretty new to struts, cant say where or why this happens but hopefully I get a few answeres here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how you are appending the data in UI??

Comment: may be you are not using .html(string)

Comment: the data is just read from database and written as one string

Comment: Are you setting it in the property attribute? `property="sb"`

Comment: .html(string)? Im not sure what is this

Comment: Its a bit more complicated, but yes. In the jsp I ask for the property.

Comment: @RaulVasi how are you appending in table in UI can you share that code also?

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal I wish, but its very complicate. Over many java classes. The "sb" will be stored in a Object with many other things and then throw a long way to a code snippet that looks like database.write(obkect.getWhatever);

Answer (score 0):

In the Java code it may not work if you entered 
 tabgs. 
Try '/n' instead of

Try using Tag Builder. TagBuilder is a class that specially designed for creating html tags and their content.

Comment: @RaulVasi did you try TagBuilder ?

Comment: @Deren Mark no, not yet. It isnt a standart java lib so befor I install a new lib in the project, I have to reseach oher solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is of pre-formmatting.
You can wrap your content with `<pre>` tag.
You should use CSS `white-space:pre` applied to the appropriate `<td>`.

Here, is a reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937218/how-to-show-multiline-text-in-a-table-cell) related to this issue.