# show array split in line breaks in primeng table

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using angular 7 with primeng

In one of my primeng table, I am getting one of column of
table as array

```
permissions: ["api-search-miscellaneous", "api-show-miscellaneous", "api-updatestatus-miscellaneous",…]
0: "api-search-miscellaneous"
1: "api-show-miscellaneous"
2: "api-updatestatus-miscellaneous"
3: "api-delete-miscellaneous"
4: "api-add-miscellaneous"
5: "api-showall-miscellaneous"
6: "api-update-miscellaneous"
```

Now primeng showing that column with comma separated , How can i show that array elements one after other in different 
line in one row only .

These are my columns , here permission is in form of array , which I am showing as group on my web page 
.ts file code

```
 this.cols = [
            {
                field: 'name',
                header: this.getLocalTranslation(
                    'Features.gridLabel.featureGroup',
                ),
            },
            {
                field: 'permissions',
                header: this.getLocalTranslation(
                    'Features.gridLabel.functionalities',
                ),
            },
        ];
```

.html file code

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
            <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
                <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                    {{ rowData[col.field] }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
```

[image]

Comment: isn't it possible to just use standard html  and/or css3:  something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937218/how-to-show-multiline-text-in-a-table-cell

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for my problem

I changed my .ts code to this one , I used Angular slice pipe and iterated through array.

```
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                <div
                    *ngIf="
                        col.field == 'permissions';
                        then content;
                        else other_content
                    "
                ></div>
                <ng-template #content>
                    <li *ngFor="let i of rowData[col.field] | slice: 0:i">
                        {{ i }}
                    </li></ng-template
                >
                <ng-template #other_content>{{
                    rowData[col.field]
                }}</ng-template>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
```