# HTML table: columns with minimum width and break-word

Tags: html, css

I want to display the following table:

```
+----+------+-------------+---------+
| id | name | description | actions |
+----+------+-------------+---------+
| .. |  ..  |     ..      |   ..    |
```

**I want that**

- the first column (id) has the minutest width possible (white-space:nowrap)
- the other columns (name, description) should break the words when necessary (word-wrap: break-word)
- the last column has also the minutest width possible (white-space:nowrap)

**What I have:**

```
 <table class="table_standard" style="word-wrap:break-word; table-layout: fixed;">
```

But with this code all columns have the same width.

How can I solve this problems?

**@thomasfuchs**

This is how it looks with a 1920x1080 monitor:
[image]

This is how it looks with a lower screen width:
[image]

And this is how it looks with an extreme low resolution:

[image]

As you can see, I want that the browser breaks the words if the resolution is too low but it just doesn't display the complete table.

This is my current code:

```
<style>
    col.id          { width: 1%; }
    col.name        { width: 20%; }
    col.description     { width: 30%; }
    col.users     { width: 30%; }
    col.games     { width: 9%; }
    col.functions     { width: 9%; }
    col.actions     { width: 1%; }
    table td:nth-child(2) { word-wrap: break-word; }
    table td:nth-child(3) { word-wrap: break-word; }
    table td:nth-child(4) { word-wrap: break-word; }
</style>
<table class="table_standard" style="word-wrap: break-word">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="id">
        <col class="name">
        <col class="description">
        <col class="users">
        <col class="games">
        <col class="functions">
        <col class="actions">
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <th class="th_titlebar" colspan="7">Alle Gruppen</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="th_subtitle">ID</th>
        <th class="th_subtitle">Name</th>
        <th class="th_subtitle">Description</th>
        <th class="th_subtitle">Members</th>
        <th class="th_subtitle">Games</th>
        <th class="th_subtitle">Functions</th>
        <th class="th_subtitle">Actions</th>
    </tr>
    //loop with data from the db
</table>
```

Comment: Do you need `table-layout:fixed`? If you remove that, and give the columns (on the `<td>` elements widths of `1%, 30%, auto, 1%` or something like that the table should be formatted like you want.

Comment: @thomasfuchs actually, if he has to do it on the table columns and inline is nessesary, then you just need to do it on the first row (normally the th element)

Comment: must the styles be inline?

Comment: Nope. One problem, I noticed now: If I delete the `table-layout: fixed`, the latest columns of the table cannot be seen anymore because the window ends there.

Comment: table: fixed, sets it to have all equal widths, no matter the content, you should do width: 100%

Comment: @Daemedeor you don't need to set it on the first row. in any case, if you want to use `table-layout:fixed`, you can set desired widths with the `colgroup` and `col` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here, it works as a dynamic way -

```html
<table class="table_standard" border='1' style='position : absolute; top : 0px left : 0px; word-wrap:break-word; text-align:center; '>
        <tr>
            <th> ID </th>
            <th> Name </th>
            <th> Description </th>
            <th> Action </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>........</td>
            <td>................</td>
            <td>.....</td>
        </tr>        
    </table>
```

If you don't want dynamic column width then try the each fixed column - the following way

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align:center; 
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style='width:30px'>ID</th>
    <th style='width:80px'>Name</th>
    <th style='width:150px'>Description</th>
    <th style='width:75px'>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>..</td>
    <td>..</td>
    <td>..</td>
    <td>..</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you don't have to make the col elements like that, you can actually put the width on the th and it should be fine....

Comment: you should actually put it into the style tag... because html5 doesn't support the width anymore... but then you should also not use the inline styles in general..... *shrug*

Comment: I don't really want to set an absolute width on a column (like 80px or 10%) because the id can go to 10000 and then absolute width wouldn't fit anymore. And when I delete the `table-layout: fixed` the words aren't broken anymore. The table has a width of 100%

Comment: @Daemedeor
how can we do that in the style tag, it will take only one value for all `th`.

Comment: <th style='width: 75px;'> that's how you use a style tag

Comment: ahh ok. I thought you are asking to put in the css file. Yes I missed the `style` tag

Comment: it should be in a css file though. I sometimes just do it inline when prototyping out a page, but the final output should be in the css file, though i don't know what the reason is not. the better idea is to use table tr th:nth-child(1), table tr td:nth-child(1) { word-wrap: nowrap } on, though that doesn't get the table to use the "least amount of space possible" which as long as he isn't using table:fixed should be a source of errors....

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5, [use the `colgroup` element, which contains `col` elements that define the desired widths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup).

```
<colgroup>
  <col class="id">
  <col class="name">
  <col class="description">
  <col class="actions">
</colgroup>
```

Insert the `colgroup` element directly under the `table` element.

You can then just use CSS to define column widths:

```
col.id          { width: 100px; }
col.name        { width: 200px; }
col.description { width: 300px; }
col.actions     { width: 100px; }
```

And so on. This is for a table with `fixed` layout. If you want the browser to dynamically adjust for the table's contents (it's unclear from your question if you want to), you can just omit the `table-layout` property (or set it to `auto`), and also use the colgroup as above to define widths. This time around, it's basically merely "hints" to the browser how to format this:

```
col.id          { width: 1%; }
col.name        { width: 30%; }
col.actions     { width: 1%; }
```

Omitting the description column should assign the rest of the width that's available to the column.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Okay this looks nice but how can I include `word-wrap: break-word`?

Comment: I'd set it for your `<td>` elements, for example: `table td:first-child { word-wrap: break-word; }` if you want `word-wrap: break-word` in the first column

Comment: I edited my first post/question and added some pictures of my problem. I also added the code which I currently use.

Comment: @Bernd: you'll have to specify a table width, e.g. `width:100%` on the table element

Comment: @Bernd: there's a few other SO questions/answers on this topic, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666532/how-to-force-table-cell-td-content-to-wrap