# Wrap long HTML tables to next line

Tags: html, css, html-table

(I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-a-html-table) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057574/html-td-wrap-text) but they are about wrapping long words)

I have a table like this:

```
<table id="myTable" width="100%" border="5" style="table-layout:fixed">
<tr>
<td><img src="photo1"></td>
<td><img src="photo2"></td>
<td><img src="photo3"></td>
<td><img src="photo4"></td>
<td><img src="photo5"></td>
<td><img src="photo6"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I need to wrap columns if user's screen width is small.
I need to wrap columns and obtain a table result like this:

I added **style="table-layout:fixed"** but this made table width exactly 100%, but images were automatically stretched to half to fit them to screen width.

How can I send columns to next line?

Comment: Don't use tables and use `float: left;` on `div`s with the width you require.

Comment: You cannot wrap cells in a row. A row is by definition always one line. That's just how a table works... You'll have to use some other method.

Comment: You can use tables, as seen here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17159819/1180926

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you need to decide is what behavior happens with the next row as it flows down to the next. Is it adding a new orphaned row, ie:

```
#container {
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 646px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    border: 5px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
#container .row {
    border: 1px solid green;
    border-left: 0;
    border-top: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#container br {
    clear: both;
}
#container .block {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 128px;
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="block">
        <img src="http://goo.gl/UohAz"/>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <img src="http://goo.gl/UohAz"/>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <img src="http://goo.gl/UohAz"/>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <img src="http://goo.gl/UohAz"/>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <img src="http://goo.gl/UohAz"/>
    </div>
     <br/>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/KFFgf/

You'll see the overflow becomes a new row with the leftover and blank space on the right.

If you just want a "rolling" block, you can:

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/KFFgf/1/

Where the rows just block down in flow. You could put `<br/>` tags in there to create hard row breaks if necessary. Not sure if that helps and haven't tested across browsers, but that's what I think you have in mind.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance Jared. Is this HTML4?

Comment: @jww Above solution is HTML4