# Wrap the text in ojtable in Ojet

Tags: oracle-jet

I am using ojtable where I want each column to be of fixed size. Whenever the text is too long in any of the column it stretches the table. Is there a possibility to wrap the text instead of stretching the column in ojtable?

Comment: check the following answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10799399/957654 and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1883702/957654

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [OJET sample from the cookbook](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=table&demo=columnContentWrapping). In your columns definition, you should set a style property:

```
"style": "white-space:normal;word-wrap:break-word; text-align: left;vertical-align: top;"
```

However, the best way is to create a class and set the class property;
component CSS file:

```
.table-world-wrap {
  white-space:normal;word-wrap:break-word; text-align: left;vertical-align: top;
}
```

component controller:

```
columns = [{
  headerText: 'your column header',
  field: 'you data field name',
  className: 'table-world-wrap'
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the table cell to [`overflow: hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).